# Hibernate refresh after stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have the following scenario:

1. Enter a @Transactional annotated class.
2. Call a stored procedure which creates rows in table X
3. Using Hibernate, get one of the newly created rows

Step 3 fails naturally since Hibernate has not been refreshed and is unaware of the newly created rows in table X.
I know there is the session.reresh(Object obj) method but since I don't have a specific object I want to refresh I don't think I can use that method.

Any thoughts of a solution to this problem?

EDIT: Even session.get() doesn't work even if I supply the entity class and an identifier representing one of the newly created rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REQUIRES_NEW in new method for just insert new entity in DB and after came back to the main transaction and fetch your entity from DB.
And also you can user session.flush() in main transaction but it commit all the changes in main transaction not just insertion your entity.
You must choice one of them base on your scenario.

Comment: I have tried this. The scenario was the following:
1. Enter a @Transactional annotated class.
2. Enter a @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
3. Call stored procedure
4. session.flush()
5. Try to get a newly created row

I'm still unable to get the row.

Comment: use transaction.commit() and session.close() in second procedure.